# Users with multiple accounts

Tags: discussion, support

In the [old meta](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/) we had a very useful thread where one could point to moderators multiple accounts to be [merged](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/605/6/merge-two-user-ids/). Since things have changed, would there be a point on having such a thread here, or what is the proper procedure if I notice a user having multiple accounts (most likely by accident) that they may like merged?

Comment: While we are at it, is there a way to search for users with unregistered accounts? Typing the user name does not return anything.

Comment: If you make a request at the [help center](http://mathoverflow.net/contact) they will investigate and merge. I don't think the accounts need to be yours (but they need to belong to the same person, of course).

Comment: Thanks, @FrançoisG.Dorais!

Comment: Just a small note: community moderators can't merge accounts anymore, only SE moderators can merge accounts.